# Call onBackpress programatically in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, back, onbackpressed

How could I perform to call the backpress function (**onWillPop**) programatically on Flutter.

In Android Native what I need to do is call this when I need to simulate a backpress click.

```
this.onBackPressed();
```

My onBackPress function, It is set to **onWillPop** inside **WillPopScope**:

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Você tem certeza?"),
                content: Text('Você realmente quer sair do app'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                    child: Text("Não")
                  ),
                  new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: _signOut,
                    child: Text("Sim")
                  ),
                ],
              ),
        ) ??
        false;
  }
```

It shows a dialog and if yes is clicked the app log out.

My ideia is to create an back arrow on AppBar to do the same

Comment: What do you want by backpress function?

Comment: Or do you want to create back button in appbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call onWillPop just call the following method on Navigator instead of pop method. It will cause flutter to call onWillPop.

```
Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
```